# best architecture to deploy TCP/IP and UDP service on amazon AWS (Without EC2 instances)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

i am traying to figure it out how is the best way to deploy a TCP/IP and UDP service on Amazon AWS. 
I made a previous research to my question and i can not find anything. I found others protocols like HTTP, MQTT but no TCP or UDP

I need to refactor a GPS Tracking service running right now in AMAZON EC2. The GPS devices sent the position data using udp and tcp protocol. Every time a message is received the server have to respond with an ACKNOWLEDGE message, giving the reception confirmation to the gps device.

The problem i am facing right now and is the motivation to refactor is: 
When the traffic increase, the server is not able to catch up all the messages. 
I try to solve this issue with load balancer and autoscaling but UDP is not supported.

I was wondering if there is something like Api Gateway, which gave me a tcp or udp endpoint, leave the message on a SQS queue and process with a lambda function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to modify the transmitting devices, e.g. to use AWS IoT Core (https://aws.amazon.com/iot-core/) or to simply enqueue their messages to SQS?

Comment: @jarmod the problem to use AWS IoT Core is, maybe i am wrong, not support udp and tcp protocol, only http/https or mqtt. I cannot change the protocol only the end point url

Comment: HTTP/S and MQTT are protocols that live **above** TCP.  We need much more detail to answer your question.

Comment: @stdunbar i know this protocols live above tcp. this devices use raw tcp connection. Socket listening specific port and keep the connection and channel alive with the device client.

Comment: Not sure why this has been down voted. I had a similar question and this was very useful.

Comment: FYI, AWS network load balancers now support UDP so you can get this solution done without 3rd party software or services. See https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/06/network-load-balancer-now-supports-udp-protocol/

Comment: Thank you! it is really good to know!

Answer (score 2):

Your question really doesn't make a lot of sense - you are asking how to run a service without running a server.

If you have reached the limits of a single instance, and you need to grow, look at using the AWS Network Load Balancer with an autoscaled group of EC2 instances.  However, this will not support UDP - if you really need that, then you may have to look at 3rd party support in the AWS Marketplace.

Edit:  Serverless architectures are designed for http based application, where you send a request and get a response.  Since your app is TCP based, and uses persistent connections, most existing serverless implementations simply won't support it.  You will need to rewrite your app to support http, or use traditional server based infrastructures that can support persistent connections.

Edit #2:  As of Dec. 2018, API gateway supports WebSockets.  This probably doesn't help with the original question, but opens up other alternatives if you need to run lambda code behind a long running connection.

Comment: Thanks for your response. when i am telling serverless architecture, i refer to this https://martinfowler.com/articles/serverless.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go more Serverless, I think the ECS Container Service has instances that accept TCP and UDP. Also take a look at running Docker Containers with with Kubernetes. I am not sure if they support those protocols, but I believe they do.

If not, some EC2 instances with load balancing can be your best bet.